# Time off at internship

Tags: internship, vacation, time-off

8 months at my current job and love it. As a recent college grad that hasn't had the funds with previous jobs like I do now, I'd love 3 weeks off for international travel. They are giving me a week off with pay this year and have treated me really well in all aspects. My position is a post-grad internship and they plan on keeping me full time after 2 yrs of internship has been used up. At what point is it reasonable to ask/how should I ask my boss the possibility of taking this time off (at some point in my career, doesn't have to be this year) without asking too much from them too soon. I don't want to seem presumptuous/ungrateful...or give them the impression I'll be asking this on an annual basis. It's a stipend based internship so there is no pto. Side note: I haven't taken hardly any time off since I've started. 
Thanks.

@VietnhiPhuvan Agreed, ASAP would be the most courteous way to go about it. However, considering I have not been with the company that long yet (8 months), is three weeks an extraordinary amount of time to ask off for at this point? Should I wait till I have a year with them first and then bring it up..? Thanks.

Comment: When are you planning to take time off?

Comment: I'm flexible with the "when" aspect so it wouldn't interfere with a busy time at work. Ideally I'd like to go late this fall or next spring, in my personal preference.

Comment: That's important for us to know. I'd say at the moment, talk to your management ASAP about taking three weeks off either in the spring or in the late fall, and tell them that you'd like to work out the specific timetable with them to minimize any disruption to them from your taking three weeks off to travel. And of course, f they want to bring anything back from your your travelling, to let you know :)

Comment: Which country are you in? What statutory holiday do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Does your company have a "leave of absence" policy?  Some companies allow you to take a "leave of absence" where you will have the space to do what you are talking about and not be penalized for it.

Check your employee handbook to check if such a thing exists and check if it is applicable to someone in your position.